# Randomly broken stick -- probabilistic approach.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I've found interesting probabilistic excersise, it seemed easy, but somehow I'm stuck.

Let's take a rod/stick of unitary length($x \in [0; 1]$). Rod is broken into two pieces in random spot.

What is needed to be found is **expected value** and **variance** of 
**the ratio of the shorter part to the longer one**.

I tried using uniform distribution, but I failed. Looking for hints, but also for an answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Notice that the ratio if broken at $x$ is the same as the ratio if broken at $1-x$. This should make your life easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.**

You cut the stick according to a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Verify that the shortest part is uniformly distributed on $[0,\frac 1 2]$. Let $X\sim \mathcal U [0,\frac 1 2]$, then what you want to find  is the expectation and the variance of the random variable $Y$ defined as: $$Y:=\frac{X} {1-X}$$
The law of unconscious statistician will help and the rest is just evaluating an integral.

Comment: Is this $Y$ supposed to be $\frac{\min (X,1-X)}{\max (X,1-X)}$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom yes, of course

Comment: @Shashi How do you end up showing that the shortest part is uniformly distributed?

Comment: @LM2357 Straightforward calculation. If the stick is broken at point $Z\sim\mathcal U[0,1]$, then $X=\min\{Z,1-Z\}$. From there one can show that $\mathbb P(X\leq x)=2x$ if $x\in [0,\frac 1 2]$ and $0$ otherwise which by definition yields the desired claim: $X\sim\mathcal U[0,\frac 1 2 ]$. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Let $Z=1$ if $X\ge1/2$, $Z=0$ otherwise. Let $Y$ be the desired variable (ratio of the shorter part to the longer one). Then ([tower rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation))

$$E[Y] = E[ E [ Y \mid Z]]=\frac12 E[Y \mid Z=0]+\frac12 E[Y \mid Z=1] \tag1$$

Because symmetry (this is not necessary, just to save some work), both terms in $(1)$ are equal, hence we can just compute $E[Y]=E[Y \mid Z=1]$

But, $X$ conditioned on $Z=1$ is uniform on $[\frac12,1]$. And $Y=\frac{1-X}{X}=\frac{1}{X}-1$

Then you just need to compute $E(1/X)$ for a uniform on $[\frac12,1]$, by a simple integral.

Computation of $E[Y^2]$, and hence variance, is similar.